# LINQ to DataSet multi-table left join

Tags: c#, linq, join

There are numerous places where it's shown how to LEFT join two tables using LINQ, but I'm having trouble adding more into the join (I have 15 tables). I thought I had the pattern down, but I'm getting an error. By the way, this is against a strongly typed DataSet, although I don't suspect that matters. Although I actually have many more tables to add into the join, I'm trying to get it working initially with fewer joins (the asterisks are where the errors are occuring):

```
var results = 
    from e in DataSetHelper.ds.Employee
    join es in DataSetHelper.ds.EmployeeSkill on e.EmployeeId equals es.EmployeeId    into esGroup from esItem in esGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join s in DataSetHelper.ds.Skill on **es.SkillId** equals s.SkillId                   into skillGroup from skillItem in skillGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join er in DataSetHelper.ds.EmployeeRole on e.EmployeeId equals er.EmployeeId     into erGroup from erItem in erGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join r in DataSetHelper.ds.Role on **er.RoleId** equals r.RoleId                      into rGroup from rItem in rGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I'm getting two errors (the same thing, but on different joins). They are on the 3rd and 5th lines of the query.

For `es.SkillId,` the error is `The name 'es' does not exist in the current context.`

For `er.RoleId,` the error is `The name 'er' does not exist in the current context.`

Again, I'll need to use this pattern for another ten joins, so I'm hoping the pattern doesn't increase in complexity as I go.

Comment: Does you dataset have more than one table.  Many case the dataset will have only one table.  You need to join a table so use either ds.Table[0] or ds.Table["Name"]

Comment: That is one complex query. Are you sure your database is normalized?

Comment: @AnupSharma Normalization is precisely the reason you have joins in a query. This database is actually less normalized than I would have made it had I designed it. With further normalization, there would be even more joins.

Comment: @jdweng There are about 15 tables in the database. Keep in mind, I'm using a strongly typed DataSet, so referencing the tables as you show isn't correct.

Comment: I don't have the context of your application but usually, you have relationships in database and EF can handle them pretty well. You don't need so many joins if relationships are correct.

Comment: @AnupSharma This is a pre-existing database. I can't change it.

Comment: What happens when you remove `into esGroup from esItem in esGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()`?

Comment: @AnupSharma If I remove those two lines (the "intos" on the many-to-many join tables), the errors go away, but I don't get the "left join" functionality that I'm shooting for. I get far fewer results than I'm expecting. Also, on a separate note, remember that I'm not even using EF (since you referenced it in an earlier comment), although I don't think that point is even relevant.

Comment: The Intos on many to many join table is ending the scope of the variable so you are getting the error. Also, the question is tagged for EF so the reference.

Comment: Oops. Removed the incorrect tag. Sorry about that. So, any ideas on how to get around that issue? As I said, I've only seen examples that use this technique on two tables.

Comment: You need to select the join into something new type and then try to join it with next entity. See my answer in Linq Expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. I also had to account for the possibility of a null on the join column. I used the null-conditional operator for that. Unfortunately, using an in-memory Dataset is just as slow as using SQL Server (and I don't even have all the joins or all the where clause tests in place). Seems like I need to use a different approach.

```
var results = from e in _data.ds.Employee
              join es in _data.ds.EmployeeSkill on e.EmployeeId equals es.EmployeeId        into esGroup from esItem in esGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join s in _data.ds.Skill on esItem?.SkillId equals s.SkillId                  into sGroup from skillItem in sGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join er in _data.ds.EmployeeRole on e.EmployeeId equals er.EmployeeId         into erGroup from erItem in erGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join r in _data.ds.Role on erItem?.RoleId equals r.RoleId                     into rGroup from rItem in rGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join et in _data.ds.EmployeeTechnology on e.EmployeeId equals et.EmployeeId   into etGroup from etItem in etGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join t in _data.ds.Technology on etItem?.TechnologyId equals t.TechnologyId   into tGroup from tItem in etGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where
                e.FirstName.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                e.LastName.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                e.RMMarket.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                !e.IsSummaryNull() && e.Summary.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
              select new SearchResult
              {
                  EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                  Name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
                  Title = e.Title,
                  ImageUrl = e.IsImageUrlNull() ? string.Empty : e.ImageUrl,
                  Market = e.RMMarket,
                  Group = e.Group,
                  Summary = e.IsSummaryNull() ? string.Empty : e.Summary.Substring(1, e.Summary.Length < summaryLength ? e.Summary.Length - 1 : summaryLength),
                  AdUserName = e.AdUserName
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var results = DataSetHelper.ds.Employee
.Join(DataSetHelper.ds.EmployeeSkill, e => e.EmployeeId, es => es.EmployeeId, (e, es) => new { e, es })
.Join(DataSetHelper.ds.Skill, esGroup  => esGroup.es.SkillId, s => s.SkillId, (esGroup, s) => new { esGroup.e, esGroup.es, s })
.Join(....
```

I have shown till the first many to many relation. It's going to be bit long for everything but I hope you can manage it.

Comment: Can that be done with query syntax? I've got a lot of other code (big where clause, etc.) and would prefer to keep that syntax.

Comment: Okay. I tried adding on a bit of my where (.Where(e.FirstName...) clause and the select. I get "e does not exist in the current context."